# Comparing the content of a cell with a string using find

Tags: python, excel, find

This might sounds like a very basic question but i'm only learning python since monday morning for my master thesis (yes, to answer every question about that, I'm really in a hurry due to unexpected circumstances), and I encountered a big problem which I cannot solve :

I would like to upload an excel file and scan some columns with find, to see if a certain character is present or not. However, I cannot success to compare the content of the cells with a string using the function find. this is my actual code:

```
import openpyxl 
from openpyxl import *


    wb = load_workbook(filename = 'test.xlsx')
    ws = wb['Feuil1']

    wb.save('balances.xlsx')
    y = ws.get_highest_column() -1
    x = ws.get_highest_row() -1
    x = int(x)
    i = 0
    j = []
    a = []
    sentence = "a"
    sentence = str(sentence)
    print(type(sentence))

    while i <= x:

        z = ws.cell(column = 1, row = i+1)
        z = str(z.value)
        c = sentence.find(z)
        print(c)
        if c > 0 :
            l = ws.cell(column = 3, row = i+1)
            j.append(l.value)
        else :
            b = ws.cell(column = 3, row = i+1) 
            a.append(b.value)

       i += 1

    print("j", j)
    print("a", a)
```

I cannot find a way to compare the real content of the cell with the string, do someone has an idea?

Thanks ! :)

Comment: How much time do you have to learn Python and write your Master's thesis?

Comment: `sentence` is one character only: `'a'`. The only way `z` can be inside it is it's 1 character long as well. So you might just check for equality. Or, maybe, you want to look for `sentence` in `z` (i.e. the other way round) with `z.find(sentence)`

Comment: I must have finished a programme for next friday, and it's a bit more complicated as i must search for different elements, both single letters and words. I modified it and it works better now (including lines to transform the analysed lines into unicode to avoid errors when analysing). I cannot post the new code as it's too long, but if you want more informations you can MP me. 

The aim of the project is to analyse the results of a web crawler on Twitter, giving me excel charts with specific tweets, and then using ANOVA and other statistical tests. Challenging but very fun ! :)